# How Content Only to Logged in Users with Specific role users?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Till Now I found this Code, But this only works as logged in or not. I want to add a role filter too.

Anyone can help me in doing it?

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
<My Content>
<?php else : ?>
<Log in to Watch Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your answer:

```
<?php   $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'admin', (array) $user->roles ) ) : ?>
       <Your Content>  
    <?php else : ?>
    <Log in to Watch Content>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do I need to Include <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?> or not.

Comment: you don't need it anymore. the wp_get_current_user will give you the current logged-in user.

Comment: Its Breaking CSS now. of div box. Check screenshot here. https://imgur.com/a/p5wvU2q

Comment: @HimanshuJain I edited my answer. you should write your HTML outside the <?PHP and ?> .. another thing, you should move the <style> tag outside the block in all cases and it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. You do not need to do `is_user_logged_in()` Condition.

```
<?php
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'USER-ROLE', (array) $user->roles ) ) :
        // YOUR-CONTENT
    else :
        // YOUR-CONTENT
    endif;
?>
```